# Use Stellar.js vertical scroll to amend horizontal position

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll, parallax

I am using **stellar.js** on a current project to produce a parallax scrolling webpage.

Whilst I have some elements using the default function (amending the element's vertical position when scrolling up and down), **I'm looking to amend this to also adjust the horizontal position.**

An example of this can be seen here (i.e. the submarine):  http://titanic.q-music.be/

I know there is 'offset' data-attribute, but I'm not sure how to get this to link to the scroll event. Any suggestions???

Thanks in advance for any help!!!!

Comment: thus far it is a very basic page as per documentation (http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the site you linked to is actually using both parralax.js (http://jonraasch.com/blog/scrolling-parallax-jquery-plugin) and scrollorama (http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/).

By using chrome's developer tools and going to the script tab, you can determine which javascript libraries are being used.

You can check out the scrollorama link for some more information on how it can be used to change the horizontal position via a vertical scroll.